# How do I convert an array in a map to array of strings

Tags: dart

I'm trying to convert this map  `{[string1,string2]}`

in to an array like this

`[string1, string2]`

in dart

Comment: is it valid map?

Comment: To be honest, I don't what it is! Is a response from one of my api calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as already mentioned in other answers this is a `Set`
you can easy convert it to List like this

```
var mySet = {['string1', 'string2']};
var list = mySet.expand((e) => e).toList();
print(list); // [string1, string2]
```

Answer (score 2):

A declaration of that kind in Dart is a Set(which is like a list but cannot have duplicates) of Lists, given that to get the first value you should just use
`obj.first`

(Sets are declared like maps but without any key)

Answer (score 2):

This is a `Set`.

So you can do this for convert it to list:

```
Set<List<String>> map = {['string1','string2']};
List list = [];
map.forEach((k) {
  k.forEach((item) => list.add(item));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'map' you gave has one key (list of strings), which seems to be missing a value.
If your map looked something like this:

```
Map<List<String>, int> map = {[string1,string2]: 0};
```

Then you could get an Iterable of your keys (or values if you wish) with:

```
dynamic temp = map.keys      //for the keys or
//or    temp = map.values    //for the values
```

You can further convert that Iterable into a List by calling the function `toList()` on it:

```
List<String> myList = temp.toList();
```

I hope this answered your question.

And if you are not sure what the type of your object is, use:

```
print(yourObject.runTimeType);
```